# How to I setup a build agent and restrict its use in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs

How do I setup a build agent and restrict its use to one teams project?

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation?

Comment: I have searched the documentation and the web and have not found the answer yet.  I have not given up.  I see how I can send a build to a specific agent, but I'd like to restrict the agent to one team as stated in my question.  I could assure you, I have put forth effort in finding the answer to my issue before posting here.

Comment: You original question is for team project, however your comment is mentioning one team. Which one are you really want to restrict its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to directly restrict the agent use in a specific team project. The agent is based on the agent pool. Suggest you take a look at [some more background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents) about what they do and how they work  especially the part of *communication with TFS*.

But you could do this in turn, restrict the team project build definitions  only use  the build agent. And the build definition is just team project level.

> You could use custom Capabilities (on your agents) and Demands (on
>   your build definitions) to ensure that particular agents are always
>   reserved for particular build scenarios.

Also take a look at this similar question: [Cannot add queue to existing TFS 2015 Build agent pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161004/cannot-add-queue-to-existing-tfs-2015-build-agent-pool)

If you want to  restrict the agent to one team, you could [set  the permissions for a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-build-release-permissions#set-the-permissions-for-a-build-definition) to only allow a specific/team group to queue the build.